# Запрос к БД из Python

Tags: mysql, python, sql, база-данных

Здравствуйте, возникла проблемка при записи данных в БД. Подскажите пожалуйста куда пихать "db.commit()", спасибо! Примерно хочу свести всё такому виду.

[image: Набросал за 2 минутки]

```
import requests
import time
from subprocess import call, PIPE
import MySQLdb

Routers = []
Hosts = []


db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",
                     user="root",
                     passwd="1234",
                     db="sqlrst",
                     charset='utf8')

cursor = db.cursor()

cursor.execute("SELECT Router FROM Routers")
Routers = cursor.fetchall()

cursor.execute("SELECT Host FROM Hosts")
Hosts = cursor.fetchall()


def HttpRequest():
    for x in Hosts:
        for z in x:
            try:
                request = requests.get(z)
                request.raise_for_status()
                cursor.execute(" UPDATE Routers SET Response = 1 WHERE Router = %s ", (z,))
            except requests.exceptions.RequestException:
                cursor.execute(" UPDATE Routers SET Response = 0 WHERE Router = %s ", (z,))

def Pinger():
    for x in Routers:
        for z in x:
            p = call("ping -n 1 " + z,
                     shell=True,
                     stdout=PIPE,
                     stderr=PIPE)
            if p != 0:
                print(x, "Unreachable")
                cursor.execute(" UPDATE Hosts SET Response = 0 WHERE Host = %s ", (z,))
            else:
                cursor.execute(" UPDATE Hosts SET Response = 1 WHERE Host = %s ", (z,))

while True:
    HttpRequest()
    Pinger()
    time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: Гм... а зачем после проверки последнего условия снова проверять наличие коннекта к БД? вроде как в схеме разрыва связи не видать...

Comment: Это нужно для проверки новых записей в базе данных. Я просто хотел узнать как грамотно записать данные в БД, спасибо.

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что вы хотите взять данные в одной таблице и поместить их в другую? Вообще реляционные базы любят, когда такое делается одним `UPDATE` или `MERGE` запросом. Ну и уж точно не надо внутри цикла на каждой итерации проверять коннект и делать коммит.

Comment: Есть программа, которая проверяет соединение с роутерами путём пинг-запроса. Полученный ответ нужно импортировать в ту же таблицу из которой берётся адрес роутера. Задача простая, а решить не могу :(